# Calling static functions with $this

Tags: php, static

I was messing around and discovered that you could actually call static methods with `$this->method()`

And it got me a bit confused and curious about the differences between the 3 ways (that I know of) to call static methods

```
$this->method();
static::method();
self::method();
```

Now, I think I understand the difference between the latter two, but what about the first one?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand the behavior of static properties in the context of class inheritance:

Static properties defined in both parent and child classes will hold DISTINCT values for each class. Proper use of `self::` vs. `static::` are crucial inside of child methods to reference the intended static property.

Static properties defined ONLY in the parent class will share a COMMON value.

```
declare(strict_types=1);

class staticparent {
    static    $parent_only;
    static    $both_distinct;

    function __construct() {
        static::$parent_only = 'fromparent';
        static::$both_distinct = 'fromparent';
    }
}

class staticchild extends staticparent {
    static    $child_only;
    static    $both_distinct;

    function __construct() {
        static::$parent_only = 'fromchild';
        static::$both_distinct = 'fromchild';
        static::$child_only = 'fromchild';
    }
}

$a = new staticparent;
$a = new staticchild;
```

More on https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 0):

> `self`   using for static method and variable in class
>
> `$this`    using for non static method and variable
>
> `static`   generally using call child class of static methods or variable 
>   For example late static

For example [late static binding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)